# If I revoke contributors on a fork of a Github repo I'm an owner of, will it revoke them on the origin?

Tags: git, github

I've seen many questions like this, but none of them exactly answer me- so I'm sorry if this is a dupe.

I am a member, and an owner, of a organisation repo. Let's call it github.com/foo/bar. On this repo there are two other owners, and a handful of lower permission users in a team.

I've forked the repo as myname/bar in order to do pull requests in a cleaner way- and hopefully everyone else will follow. The problem though is that when I just did a PR from the origin back to my fork, it sent out a notification email to everyone **except** the owners, but informs the owners when I PR from myname -> foo (desired).

I'd like to revoke access to the team on github.com/myname/bar/settings/collaboration so that no-one will be notified when I do anything on my fork, as well as not having any admin access, but I'm scared that because I have owner permissions it will reflect the changes on my foo/bar origin.

So the real question is, **are collaborators shared across the origin and all forks or are they specific to each fork?**

Many thanks in advance!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I went ahead and tried it.

**It works.**

The other members can see previous notifications & activity in their feed, but have been automatically removed from watching or having any access. They just get a 404 if they go to github.com/myname/bar!